# Typescript: same function is called on mat-select and filter data is updated globally

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

This is an angular app, In ref to my previous question [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076213/how-to-avoid-elements-overlapping-elements-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment102551707_58076213). I add table rows on clicking button. In each table row I have mat-select element, on onclick event I call a function(onclickx).
**html template**

```
<td>
   <div class="form-group">
     <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select (selectionChange) = "selectNumber($event.value)">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let type of productNo" [value]=type.num >
        {{type.num}}
       </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field> 
    </div>   
  </td>


<tr *ngFor="let product of record.products; let i = index ">
 <td>
   <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field>
     <mat-select  placeholder="Product" (click)="onclickx(i)">
      <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts" [label]="product.daemon">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let item of product.productlist" [value]="item.name">
           {{item.name}}
          </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
    </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
  </div> 
</td>
```

**typescript**

```
export class Template implements oninit{
filteredProducts:any[];
Value:number;
selectNumber (value) {
    this.Value = value;
}
  onclickx(i):any[]{
    this.Value ? this.searchTerm =this.Value : this.searchTerm ="1";
    this.filteredProducts[i] = this.searchTerm ? this.productlistArray.filter(productlistArray => productlistArray.number == this.searchTerm) : this.productlistArray;
    return this.filteredProducts;
  }
```

There will be two tables rows and each table row has this mat-select element,on clicking mat-select same function is called since "this.filteredProducts" is a global variable, when second row is updated with product list it affects the first row as well! how to overcome this problem.

Comment: `this.Value ? this.searchTerm =this.Value : this.searchTerm ="1";` this is not JS/TS. Your project should not even build with that. Please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: @Maryannah isn't that just a ternary operator that is provided by JS. Not an expert here but shouldn't you define searchterm first?

Comment: @RuudHermans this looks like it, but it's definitely not the syntax for it.